# Saving and Retrieving MKAnnotations in Swift 3 using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, mkannotation

After an exhaustive search and building of HitList and ToDo Apps, I haven't moved any closer to implementing the use of Core Data and MKAnnotations. I've see all sorts of suggestions on using NSFetchedResults, NSUserDefaults or other nonsense. I'd like to know how to implement the saving of a pin location, and then retrieve it from CoreData. Below is my futile attempt.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var storedLocations: [StoredLocations]! = []

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var markSpot: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    // Part of the Fail
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let trackingButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: mapView)
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        toolbarItems = [trackingButton, flexibleSpace, markSpot]

        mapView.delegate = self
        // More Fail
        mapView.addAnnotation(getData() as! MKAnnotation)
    }

        // Miserable Fail.. Again
        func getData() {
            do {
            storedLocations = try context.fetch(StoredLocations.fetchRequest())
            }
            catch {
                print("Fetching Failed")
            }

        }

    @IBAction func markSpotPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let userLatitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let userLongitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
        annotation.title = "Dropped Pin"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    // Another Part of the Fail
        let newPin = StoredLocations(context: context)
        newPin.latitude = userLatitude
        newPin.longitude = userLongitude
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look too far away from working; you need to loop over the objects returned into `storedLocations` and use the latitude and longitudes to re-create the annotation objects

Comment: @Paulw11 Well thats semi comforting knowing my whole day hasn't been a complete waste of reading and building demos. If I'm not too far off I'll either sleep on it, or someone will come by and help it along. My brain is fried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getData()` function doesn't return anything, and even if it did, you wouldn't want it to return an `MKAnnotation`, since you may have more than one stored object.  You can have it return an array of `MKAnnotation`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    let trackingButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: mapView)
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    toolbarItems = [trackingButton, flexibleSpace, markSpot]

    mapView.delegate = self

    if let annotations = getData() {
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }
}

func getData() -> [MKAnnotation]? {

    do {
        storedLocations = try context.fetch(StoredLocations.fetchRequest())
        var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
        for storedLocation in storedLocations {
            let newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            newAnnotation.coordinate.latitude = storedLocation.userLatitude
            newAnnotation.coordinate.longitude = storedLocation.userLongitude
            annotations.append(newAnnotation)
        }
        return annotations
    }
    catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: That solves it. Minor change on one of the variables I used in storedLocations. Thank you for the help, this question doesn't appear addressed on SO, questions sit unanswered. Now I can move forth this weekend on deleting.